# How to change material from diffuse?

Tags: materials

I'm very new to Blender, and I've been watching the Blender Guru tutorials. I've gotten to the materials episode, and the person in the video has a dropdown menu to change the texture from Diffuse to Glossy or any number of others. I can't seem to find a way to change from Diffuse, and I'm very confused.

I'm in Blender 2.79 if that helps, thanks.

Comment: Would you mind providing a link of the video you were watching so I can get an idea of what they were doing. Also a timestamp of at what point they did this action?

Comment: Can you even see Diffuse?

Comment: The video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Gb1VK98Wc
The timestamp is 14:50 where he selects the dropdown menu for `Surface` and can change it from Diffuse, Glossy, etc etc.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing: https://imgur.com/a/BxLnh4j
As you can see, under the `Preview` dropdown, I have a `Diffuse` dropdown but not a `Surface` dropdown as shown in the video. Again, I am in 2.79.
@nathanrivera
@Yash

Comment: Maybe you need to switch from Blender Render to Cycles Render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to switch from *Blender Render* to *Cycles Render*

[image]